# Image Upload save file name on database using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

please help me to create a image upload system using Laravel 5.4 and also can save the filename at the database...
[image]

i can't find any related article about this and i also tried a youtube tutorial but it doesn't explain how filename transferred on the database, hope you can help mo on this
thank you...

here so far my code that i done...

```
$this->validate(request(), [
        'article_banner' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png | max:2000',
        'article_title' => 'required|max:255',
        'article_date' => 'required|date',
        'article_content' => 'required',
        ]
    );

    $article_banner = $request->file('article_banner');
    $article_title = $request->input('article_title');
    $article_date = $request->input('article_date');
    $article_content = $request->input('article_content');

    return $article_banner;
}
```

also here's my error on validation every time i upload a docx... not image
[image]

here's the article_add.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">User Management -> Edit User</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('article_add.post') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('article_banner') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="article_banner" class="col-md-4 control-label">Article Banner: </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="article_banner" type="file" class="form-control" name="article_banner" required autofocus>
                                <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                                @if ($errors->has('article_banner'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('article_banner') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('article_title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="article_title" class="col-md-4 control-label">Article Title: </label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="article_title" type="text" class="form-control" name="article_title" value="{{ old('article_title') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('article_title'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('article_title') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('article_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="article_date" class="col-md-4 control-label">Article Date: </label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="article_date datepicker" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="article_date" value="{{ old('article_date') }}" data-provide="datepicker" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('article_date'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('article_date') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('article_content') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div style="padding:10px;">
                                <label for="article_content">Article Date: </label>
                                <br />
                                <textarea id="content article_content" type="text" class="form-control" name="article_content" autofocus>{{ old('article_content') }}</textarea>
                            </div>
                            @if ($errors->has('article_content'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('article_content') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                         @if(session()->has('message'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                {{ session()->get('message') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        @if(session()->has('errors'))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{ session()->get('errors') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Submit
                                </button>
                                 <a href="{{ url('article_management') }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Back
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error messages do you get? Which specific part are you having problems with?

Comment: im trying to get the filename of the image that i upload to save it at the database... then i try to return the $article_banner = $request->file('article_banner'); the filename is not showing also the validation for image 'article_banner' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png | max:2000', is not working also.... i got errors htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given...

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. Can you update your original post with the code you've tried and format it too please? Also include the message (htmlsepcialchars() or whatever you get) and where you get it.

Comment: done updating my post...

Comment: can you post the code of article_add.php and the code of your form

Comment: @Exprator done on posting it...

Comment: bro see one thing, you told docx is giving error right? but in validation you are only allowing images, then now what you need? docx will give error as you have mentioned it so

Comment: @Exprator yes... im trying to create a validation that when a user try to upload a non image file... the system will say invalid file...

Comment: @ivor added one ans. can you try it once and let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

make one function as

```
public function uploadFiles($_destination_path, $images, $new_file_name) { //code to uplaod multiple fiels to path and return paths array wit file names
    $file_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $new_file_name);
    $paths = array('path' => $_destination_path . '/' . basename(Storage::disk($this->diskStorage)->putFileAs($_destination_path, $images, $file_name)),
        'name' => pathinfo($file_name));
    return $paths;
}
```

And pass required argument to it like as

```
$image = $request->file('image');
$fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$destinationPath = '/images';
$img_path[] = $this->uploadFiles($destinationPath, $image, $fileName);
```

You will get required data in the img_path[] array variable.

Comment: Upload files first, when you get name as I say, then pass it to the DB array, you need to create array manually.

Comment: i got an error... Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::store()

Comment: Check arguments are not going blank. Also use public storage at local in filesystem config. and make a storage link also. You can refer laravel documentation for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
public function feedbackPost(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $fileName1 = "";
        $fileName2 = "";
        $rules = array(
            'conferencename' =>'required',
            'yourname' =>'required',
            'email' =>'required',
            'objective' =>'required',
            'results' =>'required',
            'recommendations' =>'required',
            'key_customers' =>'required',
            'actions' =>'required',
            'business_opportunities' =>'required',
            'other_opportunities' =>'required',
            'upload_leads' =>'mimes:csv,xls,xlsx', 
            'upload_attendees' =>'mimes:csv,xls,xlsx',
            );

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) 
        {
            return back()->with('danger', 'File format not valid');
        }
        else 
        {
            if($file=$request->hasFile('upload_attendees')) {
                $file=$request->file('upload_attendees');
                $fileName1=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                if (!file_exists('uploads/feedback/attendees/'.$id.'')) {
                mkdir('uploads/feedback/attendees/'.$id.'', 0777, true);
                }
                $destinationPath='uploads/feedback/attendees/'.$id.'';
                $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName1);
            }

            if($file=$request->hasFile('upload_leads')) {
                $file=$request->file('upload_leads');
                $fileName2=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                if (!file_exists('uploads/feedback/leads/'.$id.'')) {
                mkdir('uploads/feedback/leads/'.$id.'', 0777, true);
                }
                $destinationPath='uploads/feedback/leads/'.$id.'';
                $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName2);
            }
            $feedback = Feedback::insert([
                                        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
                                        'conferenceid' => $request->conferenceid,
                                        'conferencename' =>$request->conferencename,
                                        'yourname' =>$request->yourname,
                                        'email' =>$request->email,
                                        'objective' =>$request->objective,
                                        'results' =>$request->results,
                                        'recommendations' =>$request->recommendations,
                                        'key_customers' =>$request->key_customers,
                                        'actions' =>$request->actions,
                                        'business_opportunities' =>$request->business_opportunities,
                                        'other_opportunities' =>$request->other_opportunities,
                                        'upload_attendees' =>$fileName1,
                                        'upload_leads' =>$fileName2,
                                            ]);
            }
        return back()->with('success', 'Thanks! Your Feedback has been Submitted!');
    }
```

This is how I did. You may try this.